# Pandas - Groupby rename column name

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to rename the new aggregated column name in the groupBy function.

My code:

```
groupByColumns = ['clientId', 'state', 'branchId']
aggColumn = 'amount'
aggOperation = sum
comNewColName = totalSalesDone

result = df.groupby(groupByColumns)[aggColumn].agg(aggOperation)
```

This here it is working perfectly. Now I am trying to rename the aggeregated new column:

```
result = df.groupby(groupByColumns, as_index=False).agg(comNewColName=(aggColumn,aggOperation))
```

But I am getting column name comNewColName but I need to get totalSalesDone.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you have to make the new column name a string. Try it like this: `comNewColName = "totalSalesDone"`

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack a dictionary in [Named Aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html?highlight=filter#named-aggregation)

Here is an example:

```
from seaborn import load_dataset    
df_tips = load_dataset('tips')

aggcol = 'total_bill'
newColumnSum='Sum_Total_Bill'
aggop = 'sum'
df_tips.groupby('sex')[[aggcol]].agg(**{f'{newColumnSum}':(f'{aggcol}',f'{aggop}')})
```

Output:

```
        Sum_Total_Bill
sex                   
Male           3256.82
Female         1570.95
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just get rid of "comNewColName = totalSalesDone"
`result['totalSalesDone'] = df.groupby(groupByColumns, as_index=False).agg(aggColumn,aggOperation))`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `sum`, but should pass `'sum'` (as a string) in a [grouped named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html). That should solve your issue. So I believe changing:

```
aggOperation = sum
```

to:

```
aggOperation = 'sum'
```

And doing:

```
result = df.groupby(groupByColumns, as_index=False).agg(comNewColName=(aggColumn,aggOperation))
```

Should work.